# How to hide tabbar from one xib to another on button clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a TabBar class named GTabBar and it's items are define on AppDelegate class. The TabBar show in the 1st Xib. When I click a button then move to the another Xib. When it move to anther Xib I need to hide the TabBar. So how can I do that? Please answer with a example code.

Comment: are you use push operation xib for move ?

Comment: yes i use push operation like:
    UIViewController * newView = [[show_list_inhabitants alloc] initWithNibName:@"show_list_inhabitants" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:NO];

Comment: please share your GTabBar define and alloc code?

Comment: try this : newView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController: newView animated:YES];

Comment: tabBarHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height, 320, 480)];
 tabBarHolder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 //add it as a subview
 [self.view addSubview:tabBarHolder];

Comment: newView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];        this code does not work

Comment: how to use this code ... put in question .

Comment: Please check the code: 1st TabBar class named "GTabBar" where I create TabBar: tabBarHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height, 320, 480)]; tabBarHolder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; [self.view addSubview:tabBarHolder]; 2nd in the "AppDelegate' where decraled item works: _tabItem1 = [[GTabTabItem alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 30, 30) normalState:@"attraction.png" toggledState:@"attraction.png"]; [_tabItem1 addTarget:self action:@selector(inhabitantFunc) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: - (IBAction)landModeButton:(id)sender { UIViewController * newView = [[LandModeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandModeVC" bundle:nil]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:NO]; } --------Using this code move to next Xib, and when I move to next Xib then need to hide the TabBar on next Xib

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    tabBarHolder.hidden = YES;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

or try this

```
UIViewController *newView = [[show_list_inhabitants alloc] initWithNibName:@"show_list_inhabitants" bundle:nil];
tabBarHolder.hidden = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:NO];
```

Comment: Please check the code: 1st TabBar class named "GTabBar" where I create TabBar: tabBarHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height, 320, 480)]; tabBarHolder.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; [self.view addSubview:tabBarHolder]; 2nd in the "AppDelegate' where decraled item works: _tabItem1 = [[GTabTabItem alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5, 30, 30) normalState:@"attraction.png" toggledState:@"attraction.png"]; [_tabItem1 addTarget:self action:@selector(inhabitantFunc) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: - (IBAction)landModeButton:(id)sender { UIViewController * newView = [[LandModeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandModeVC" bundle:nil]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:NO]; } --------Using this code move to next Xib, and when I move to next Xib then need to hide the TabBar on next Xib

Comment: try `tabBarHolder.hidden = YES;` when `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` on next Xib class

Comment: I have to use this code using the outlet of GTabBar class right?

Comment: yes, based on outlet of GTabBar hide it when viewWillAppear